# Stringify in objects JSON inside a object JSON

Tags: javascript, json

This is my object JSON:

```js
var myJSon = {
    "Student": "name",
    "Answers":{ 
        "Answer1": {
            "question": "question",
            "answer": "black",
            "time": "00:02:30",
            "number_tentatives": "1"
        },
        "Answer2": {
            "question": "question",
            "answer": "black",
            "time": "00:02:30",
            "number_tentatives": "2"
        }
    }
};
```

I need to fill in the object "Answer1" or "Answer2". I tried

```
myJSon.Respostas = JSON.stringify("One","hello","00:03:22","1");
```

But this results in `{Student":"\"name\"","Answers":"\"oi\"}`

What I would like is `{"Student": "\"name\"", "Answers": {"Answer1": {"question": "One", "answer": "hello" ,"time":"00:03:22" ,"number_tentatives": "1"}, "`

Comment: sorry my bad english and the format of text in stack overflow

Comment: The `JSON.stringify` command that you show seems to have no relation whatsoever to the rest of the question. Never mind that it's wrong as it is, it's completely different data. When I `JSON.stringify` the object in variable `myJSon` (why is it called JSON? it's an object! JSON is a `string`!) I get the correct result. You are not telling us everything. With the given information your problem cannot be reproduced. Please provide a reproducible example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: all right, forget stringify for now, i just need change values of Answer1 and Answer2, stringify is just a method that i tried for pass the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an object containing multiple answers, it should be an array or map of answers.

Let's think of your object's initial state as this:

`var myJson = {student: 'Student Name', answers: []};`

So then you could start filling the answers array like:

`myJson.answers.push({question: 'q', answer: 'a', time: 1, number_tentatives: 1});`

If you'd now access `myJson.answers` it would be an array with one answer in it.

If you still think the way to go would be objects (so a 'key' is assigned to each answer), you would do this, instead of `push`:

`myJson.answers['answer1'] = {question: 'q', answer: 'a', time: 1, number_tentatives: 1};`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add additional data, then you could try this:

```
myJSon.Answers.Answer3 ={"question":"One","answer":"hello","time":"00:03:22","number_tentatives":"1"};
```

then test it like

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(myJSon));
```